# how to get value before child process halt in bash

Tags: bash, child-process

Requirement is:

1. child process will return a value, IP address, it use wget method
2. but child process maybe halt.
3. parent process can not wait child process, it need return value after some second.

The possible script is

parent.sh:

```
./child.sh & 
sleep 60 
echo child_return_value
```

child.sh:

```
child_return_value=$(wget ipaddress)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add another possible approach, you can capture the output of a background process without (manually) using files by using process substitution, if your shell supports it. You can use the `read` builtin to get the output, which allows setting a timeout value:

```
exec 3< <(wget -O- ipaddress);
read -r -u3 -t60;
return_value="$REPLY";
exec 3<&-;
echo "$return_value";
```

The shell will actually create a FIFO or /dev/fd/xx special file on your behalf under this solution.

Comment: thanks, but it seems exec only run in shell not in script, how to mitigate this?

Comment: A script is a file of shell commands. When you run the script, the shell reads each line and runs the commands, pretty much exactly as if they were typed by a human user at the shell prompt. `exec` should work both interactively (i.e. at the shell prompt) and in a script. What error are you seeing?

Comment: ./get_current_ip.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

./get_current_ip.sh: line 9: `exec 3< <(wget -q -O - "http://checkip.dyndns.com/");'

but I run in this line in shell is OK.

Comment: It's likely that you've set the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line in your script to `#!/bin/sh`, but the shell you're running interactively is bash, likely located at /bin/bash. The old-timey [Borne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) sh supports fewer features than the new [Bourne-again shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) bash; bash supports process substitution, while sh does not. Try changing the shebang to `#!bash`, or use the full path if you can (possibly `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Both sh and bash are shells. The commands you run interactively as well as the commands run from inside a script are running in a shell. For a single shell, there are normally very few differences between interactive mode and script mode, however, if you run a different shell for interactive work than you do for script execution, you'll see significant differences. sh and bash are quite similar (bash descended from sh), but they still have significant differences. You should always try to run the same shell interactively as you do for scripts. (bash is the right choice as it's more advanced.)

Answer (score 3):

I would use the -T|--timeout option of wget to have the request time out after a specified number of seconds. If you do this, you can avoid messing with background processes and IPC entirely:

```
return_value=$(wget -T60 -O- ipaddress); ## 60 sec timeout
echo "$return_value";
```

Comment: thanks very much, it is my difficulty, wget of openwrt don't have -T options.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the child process write the result to a file that the parent process can read.

```
child_out="$(mktemp)"
./child.sh > "$child_out" &
sleep 60
if [ -s "$child_out" ]
then
    child_return_value=$(cat "$child_out")
else
    # Child did not produce a result yet.
fi
```

Don't forget to remove the temporary file in the parent script.  Preferably using a trap so it will be removed under all (well, most) circumstances.

Comment: thanks, it will be better if don't use temporary file.